# To extract the pixel values using point shapefile as feature Collection of time series data (landsat 8) and export it in csv, in python using geemap()

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, landsat, geemap

Error occured: "The image must be an instance of ee.Image.", for the following code.

```
import os
import ee
import geemap
ee.Initialize()
Map = geemap.Map()
Map
india = ee.FeatureCollection("users/GEE_work/INDIA_WITH_KASHMIR")
collection = (
ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T2_L2")
.filter(ee.Filter.date('2014-01-01', '2022-12-31'))
.select(['SR_B5'])
.filterBounds(india)
)
vis = {
'min': 1,
'max': 65455,
'palette': ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD165', '99B718', '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601',      '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'        
]
}
gpp = collection.toBands()
Map.addLayer(collection, vis, "L8 nir")
Map.setCentre(79,30,8)
Map
work_dir = os.path.expanduser('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Downloads')
pt = ee.FeatureCollection("users/GEE_work/stations")
out_csv = os.path.join(work_dir, 'L8_B5_NIR_2014_22.csv')
geemap.extract_values_to_points(pt, collection, out_csv)
```

I am expecting a csv file with pixel values of given point shapefile, of Landsat data from 01-01-2014 to 31-12-2022. It would be very helpful if I get pixel values only for Band 5 (NIR) and Band 6 (SWIR), separately.

Comment: `EEException: Collection.loadTable: Collection asset 'users/GEE_work/INDIA_WITH_KASHMIR' not found.` ?

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/GEE_work/INDIA_WITH_KASHMIR

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/GEE_work/stations